# Hide keyboard from search bar in CollectionViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

While my problems seems easy to solve I cannot do it myself.

Basically I got my CollectionViewController that holds all of my data and I've included within it a search bar which filters items from my collection depending on what the user writes.

When an user taps on any item it leads them to another view and so on.

And when the user taps on the search bar, the keyboard shows up and I'd like to hide it whenever the user decides to tap somewhere else.

While I can do that it turns out that every time I hide the keyboard with the methods I found, it also prevents the user from going further into my application, in fact it's not longer possible to go to another view after tapping on them.

Here's what I did :

My CollectionViewController.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Setup search bar/collection view
        self.collectionView?.dataSource = self
        searchBar.delegate = self
        searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
        navigationItem.titleView = searchBar

        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

func dismissKeyboard() {

       searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }
```

I also tried many things found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530160/uitextview-focused-but-user-touches-uicollectionviewcell-hide-keyboard-and-run) without success. Somehow even if I've included the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate in my file some delegate listed there aren't triggered when I tap somewhere. For example the delegate `gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool` doesnt work.

I can see the logic right here, but it's just impossible to find any fix that doesn't break the collectionview.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Try to do `view.endEditing(true)` instead of `searchBar.resignFirstResponder()`. It might work.

Comment: It does the same unfortunately. The transitions between my views are segues, could it somehow breaks when you add a gestureRecognizer?

Comment: Dear @CroiSciento I have posted solution for your question.

Answer (score 2):

Please use below solution for both **Objective-c & Swift**, I hope it will work for you dear
**Swift**
create variable **let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer()** and in **viewDidLoad** method write below code.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);
}
```

And paste below code for further implementation of methods:

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
} 
func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    view.removeGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
```

**(Objective-c)** First of all create **UITapGestureRecognizer *tap** variable and in **viewDidLoad** method paste below code.

```
//Notifications for keyBoardShow and keyBoradHide 
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

And paste below code:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notif {
//Add tap gesture here
tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                               initWithTarget:self
                               action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notif {
  //Remove tap gesture
  [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:tap];
}
-(void)dismissKeyboard {
   [yourSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

@CroiSciento dear check this solution.

Answer (score 1):

check this out

```
override func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}
```